# Seeking source for a quip about when it's ok to publish a theorem

Tags: reference-request, publishing

Long ago, perhaps 40-50 years ago, I read a paper or book that contained advice about how to write and publish mathematics that contained a certain quip (below).   Perhaps it was something published by the AMS, or perhaps it was written by Paul Halmos.   Anyway, although I've tried, I've not been able to find it again.   In my (admittedly deficient) memory, it went something like this:

**Do not attempt to publish case x of a theorem in the year 1950+x.**

Does anyone recognize this and know the source?

Comment: Not sure what it means. What is a "case" of a theorem? An application?

Comment: A theorem is often parameterized by some variable x, and the general statement would be about all x.   But if one cannot prove the general statement, one might well work out proofs for x =1, x= 2, and so forth.   The advice is that it is not good professional practice to publish each of these in turn as separate papers.

As an example of common usage, people often talk about "the case n = 3 of Fermat's last theorem", and so forth.

Comment: The Halmos article you're referring to is probably [How to write mathematics](http://www.di.ens.fr/~bouillar/Stages/Halmos-How-To-Write.pdf), but I don't remember if it contains what you are looking for.

Comment: It is also included in Steenrod, Norman Earl; Halmos, Paul R.; Schiffer, Menahem M.; Dieudonné, Jean A., How to write mathematics. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS) (ISBN 978-0-8218-0055-3/pbk). 64 p. (1973).

Comment: Thanks, I looked at the Halmos article, but I did not see it there.

Comment: Halmos adds, "A striking criterion for how to decide not to publish something was offered by my colleague John Conway. Suppose that you have just finished typing a paper. Suppose now that I come to you, horns, cloven hooves, forked tail and all, and ask: if I gave you $\$1000.00$, would you tear the paper up and forget it? If you hesitate, your paper is lost - do not publish it."

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The statement is in Halmos, What to publish, Monthly January 1975, Page 15. "Do not publish in 1975 the case of dimension 2 of an interesting conjecture in algebraic geometry, one that you don't know how to settle in general, and then follow it by dimension 3 in 1976, dimension 4 in 1977, and so on, with dimension $k-3$ in 197k."

Comment: P. R. Halmos, "ii. What to Publish", *The American Mathematical Monthly,* Vol. 82, No. 1, January 1975, pp. 14-17, https://doi.org/10.1080/00029890.1975.11993762 Apparently this was the second of a series of four panel talks.

Comment: So Halmos' "What to publish" contains case 1973 of this theorem. But the OP was asking about case 1950. Maybe it was published separately?

Comment: @Stef, I assume you're joking, but if not, I'll note that OP qualified his question with "In my (admittedly deficient) memory, it went something like this:" It is possible that Halmos or someone else published a 1950 version of the quip, but I take it that OP remembered the gist, but not the detail.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes I was joking.

Comment: There is a related saying in Chemistry, don't publish about methyl derivatives in year 1, ethyl in year 2, propyl in year 3, butyl in year 4 and so futile in year 5.